# Issue with matrix slicing in n-deminsional matrix

Tags: python

I was stuck in python function, but later solved it. I have a question regarding the python n-dimensional notation. That matrix was A(2,4,4,3). So what's the difference in accessing the matrix as A[:][0:3, 0:3, 3] and A[:][ 0:3, 0:3 ][3]

Comment: The initial slicing `[:]` does nothing. `[0:3, 0:3, 3]` is indexing along the first 3 axes. `[ 0:3, 0:3 ][3]` is indexing along the first 2 axes, and then indexing the resulting ndarray. More on indexing [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test array(2,4,4,3):

```
[[[[ 0  1  2]   [[[48 49 50]
   [ 3  4  5]     [51 52 53]
   [ 6  7  8]     [54 55 56]
   [ 9 10 11]]    [57 58 59]]

  [[12 13 14]    [[60 61 62]
   [15 16 17]     [63 64 65]
   [18 19 20]     [66 67 68]
   [21 22 23]]    [69 70 71]]

  [[24 25 26]    [[72 73 74]
   [27 28 29]     [75 76 77]
   [30 31 32]     [78 79 80]
   [33 34 35]]    [81 82 83]]

  [[36 37 38]    [[84 85 86]
   [39 40 41]     [87 88 89]
   [42 43 44]     [90 91 92]
   [45 46 47]]]   [93 94 95]]]
```

With data[0:4, 0:4, 1] you getting each second element from 4x4 array:

```
[[[ 3  4  5]   [[51 52 53]
  [15 16 17]    [63 64 65]
  [27 28 29]    [75 76 77]
  [39 40 41]]   [87 88 89]]]
```

On the other hand with data[0:4, 0:4][1] you will get second part of 4x4x2 array:

```
[[[48 49 50]
  [51 52 53]
  [54 55 56]
  [57 58 59]]

 [[60 61 62]
  [63 64 65]
  [66 67 68]
  [69 70 71]]

 [[72 73 74]
  [75 76 77]
  [78 79 80]
  [81 82 83]]

 [[84 85 86]
  [87 88 89]
  [90 91 92]
  [93 94 95]]]
```